# Use XML URL as View in Lotus Notes

Tags: xml, url, view, lotus-notes

I have a plain vanilla XML output that I want to display in Lotus Notes as a view. Is there a way to use the XML URL as the basis for a view?

Answer (score 1):

A view displays data contained in a collection of Notes documents. That's all it does. So the only way to show the data from your XML URL in a Notes view would be to write code that parses the XML and saves the data in Notes documents.